# Non-Alcoholic Distillation

Tags: non-alcoholic

Ultimately, I would love to know how the folks over at
[Seedlip](https://www.seedlipdrinks.com/) have managed to make a distilled beverage with no alcohol. What would the process roughly consist of if sugar isn't used?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

They just don't ferment to create any alcohol in the first place. Pretty sure it is just [aromatic waters](http://www.newdruginfo.com/pharmacopeia/bp2003/British%20Pharmacopoeia%20Volume%20III%5CMonographs%5CFormulated%20Preparations%20Genearal%20Monographs%5CAROMATIC%20WATERS.htm). Distillation to intensify some flavors.